# How to save v-model input as it is being entered

Tags: javascript, vue.js, input

I am trying to mask a number on user input to hide all but the last 4 digits while they are typing.
The important part is that the original value that is not masked needs to be stored without the *** in it.

```
    },`
```

My current code changes both the input that the user sees in the text field (good) and the oValue (bad) I need the oValue to remain as a number that has not been masked.

EG:

oValue = 123456789
numInput = *****6789

**the text field:**

`<v-text-field  v-model="numInput" @input="maskNum"`

**the method:**

`maskNum(numToMask) {                         this.oValue = numToMask                         this.numInput = numToMask.replace(/\d(?=\d{4})/g, '*')          },`

Comment: Why are you both using v-model and an input handler that both use this.numInput? Drop your v-model and replace it with the value you want to show.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.